# Angular 2 http delete doesn't make network requests

Tags: http, angular

Other verbs work fine to my api but delete doesn't fire anything in the network tab on chrome Dev tools

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I guess that you forgot to subscribe on the request. Observables are lazy so you need to subscribe to actually execute them. It must be done even if you don't expect a payload in the response.

Something like that:

```
this.http.delete().subscribe((res) => {
});
```